Datasource ${Prometheus} was not found" in Grafana
I am trying to integrate Kafka KRaft metrics with Prometheus and Grafana. I am testing on a CentOS 7 environment, and I am currently using the latest versions of Prometheus and Grafana.
When I try to view the metrics through the dashboard in Grafana, the following error occurs.

kafka-cluster.json:
 ....
     {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "${Prometheus}"
      },
      "description": "Number of active controllers in the cluster.",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "mappings": [
            {
              "options": {
                "match": "null",
                "result": {
                  "text": "N/A"
                }
              },
              "type": "special"
            }
          ],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "#299c46",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "#e5ac0e",
                "value": 2
              },
              {
                "color": "#bf1b00"
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "none"
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
 ....

dashboard.yml:
apiVersion: 1

providers:
    - name: "Prometheus"
      orgId: 1
      folder: ""
      type: file
      disableDeletion: false
      allowUiUpdates: true
      editable: true
      options:
          path: /home/kafka/grafana/conf/provisioning/dashboards

datasource.yml:
# config file version
apiVersion: 1

# list of datasources that should be deleted from the database
#deleteDatasources:
#  - name: Prometheus
#    orgId: 1

# list of datasources to insert/update depending
# whats available in the database
datasources:
  # <string, required> name of the datasource. Required
- name: Prometheus
  # <string, required> datasource type. Required
  type: prometheus
  # <string, required> access mode. direct or proxy. Required
  access: proxy
  # <int> org id. will default to orgId 1 if not specified
  orgId: 1
  # <string> url
  url: http://prometheus:9090
  # <string> database password, if used
  password:
  # <string> database user, if used
  user:
  # <string> database name, if used
  database:
  # <bool> enable/disable basic auth
  basicAuth: true
  # <string> basic auth username
  basicAuthUser: admin
  # <string> basic auth password
  basicAuthPassword: foobar
  # <bool> enable/disable with credentials headers
  withCredentials:
  # <bool> mark as default datasource. Max one per org
  isDefault: true
  # <map> fields that will be converted to json and stored in json_data
  jsonData:
     # <sting> the typical scrap and evaluation interval configured in Prometheus, used to calculate '$__rate_interval'
     timeInterval: 60s
     tlsAuth: false
     tlsAuthWithCACert: false
  # <string> json object of data that will be encrypted.
  secureJsonData:
    tlsCACert: "..."
    tlsClientCert: "..."
    tlsClientKey: "..."
  version: 1
  # <bool> allow users to edit datasources from the UI.
  editable: true


After investigating, I found that the issue is with the uid value in the .json file. How can I resolve this problem?

Please use texts (formatted as code) instead of images

Not just a suggestion, a requirement if you want help ^.

Thank you for letting me know. I have made the corrections.
